# Groovy Script .xml parsing

Tags: groovy

Please help: : how can I deal with each of these in a .each or For Each or whatever? I have a .xml I am trying to parse with a Groovy script.  Here is the .xml:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
         maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
         keystoreFile="/something/q2_reports/server_QA1/keystorea.jks" keystorePass="password"
         clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Here is my Groovy script:

```
def Server1 = new XmlParser().parse('c:\\temp\\server.xml')
Server1.Service.Connector.each {
    println "Stuff in Connector: ${it}"
}
```

Here is it's results:

```
Stuff in Connector: Connector[attributes={port=8080, URIEncoding=UTF-8, protocol=HTTP/1.1, connectionTimeout=20000, redirectPort=8443}; value=[]]

Stuff in Connector: Connector[attributes={port=8443, protocol=HTTP/1.1, SSLEnabled=true, maxThreads=150, scheme=https, secure=true, keystoreFile=/cwtapp/e2_reports/jasper_server_QA1/keystore.jks, keystorePass=password, clientAuth=false, sslProtocol=TLS}; value=[]]

Stuff in Connector: Connector[attributes={port=8009, protocol=AJP/1.3, redirectPort=8443}; value=[]]
```

My question is: what code can I put within the code block of

```
Server1.Service.Connector.each {
    println "Stuff in Connector: ${it}"
}
```

in order to print off each of the items individually, like 'port' and 'protocol' and such, for every instance of the .xml block 'Connector'?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

```
def Server1 = new XmlParser().parse('c:\\temp\\server.xml')
Server1.Service.Connector.each {
    println 'Attributes of Connector:'
    it.attributes().each { println it }
    println()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add attribute name, value extraction to the previous answer. The following:

```
def str = '''\
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
         maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
         keystoreFile="/something/q2_reports/server_QA1/keystorea.jks" keystorePass="password"
         clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
  </Service>
</Server>'''

def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(str)
xml.Service.Connector.indexed(1).each { i, connectorNode -> 
  println "\nConnector $i"
  connectorNode.attributes().each { k, v -> 
    println "$k -> $v"
  }
}
```

prints:

```
Connector 1
port -> 8080
URIEncoding -> UTF-8
protocol -> HTTP/1.1
connectionTimeout -> 20000
redirectPort -> 8443

Connector 2
port -> 8443
protocol -> HTTP/1.1
SSLEnabled -> true
maxThreads -> 150
scheme -> https
secure -> true
keystoreFile -> /something/q2_reports/server_QA1/keystorea.jks
keystorePass -> password
clientAuth -> false
sslProtocol -> TLS

Connector 3
port -> 8009
protocol -> AJP/1.3
redirectPort -> 8443
```

you can write just:

```
xml.Service.Connector.each { connectorNode ->
```

if you don't need the indexes in the above answer.